# Giving www-data user access to message bus to run Puppeteer/Chromium

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions, puppeteer, chromium

We're trying to run Puppeteer with Chromium through a web page. We have a NodeJS script responsible for activating Puppeteer/Chromium which is called by a PHP script.
Our environment is Ubuntu 22.04 running Apache2.

The NodeJS script runs well on root, performing its task. However, since we want to be able to call this functionality from a webpage, we're trying to execute it via the Apache user www-data. When attempting to do so, we encounter an error:

```
   /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:299
            reject(new Error([
                   ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
2023/01/17 18:54:59.140880 cmd_run.go:1055: WARNING: cannot start document portal: dial unix /run/user/0/bus: connect: permission denied
/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-74.scope is not a snap cgroup


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:299:20)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:287:24)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:536:10)
    at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:262:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v18.7.0
```

Based on the error it seems to be a permissions issue with the message bus. When changing the ownership of /run/user/0/bus to www-data we still get a "permission error" trying to access it with the www-data user. No matter what "chmod" we give it, the permissions are always srwxrwxr-x. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have a similar issue.

Comment: I did, I apparently had multiple Puppetteer instances installed. I removed all of them, then reinstalled a clean installation. That seemed to do the trick.